# how to obtain the images cache form android-4.4 WebView

Tags: android, webview, android-4.4-kitkat

When I visit a website (containing some text and a few images), the cache directory in /data/data/com.mayexample/app_webview/Cache gets filled with a few files called 4f42185de3a3a461_0, 4f42185de3a3a461_1,et4f42185de3a3a461_2  etc.
I can't do anything with the cache's files.
Do you know a way to open webview cache files? Doesn't one file represent a corresponding cached image for example? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the Browser engine (actually the HTTP module) maintains such cached files in a URL-to-HashKey manner. So what you found (such as "4f42185de3a3a461_1") may be associated with any web resource files such as JS/CSS/images/HTML, etc.

I remember WebView used to store such URL-to-HashKey mapping data in sqlite3 tables in earlier Android versions.

The problem here is you have no idea about the mapping relations so you can hardly retrieve the file you want. A tricky way is to read the AOSP source code then you may be able to know how the generate the HashKey by an unique URL, or you can manipulate the sqlite3 tables, if there are still any on Android 4.4.